# Aurora average active sessions and Active connection count

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am looking at database connection uses metrics for my application. My application uses JPA + hibernate to connect to Aurora DB database.

I see that my application is making ~ 220 active connection with database and with 60 pods in the application, total number of active connections is in the range of ~12K.
If I look at database side, I see Aurora Dashboard shows only like 50 AAS ( average active sessions ) created at DB end.

My question is - From my understanding AAS should be in same range as number of active connection. Is this understanding correct ? Is there any way to correlate AAS with number of active connection ?